# Complement of "require" in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, complements, idiomatic-language

I wrote:

> In general, the proposed methods search for repetitive structures to identify data regions. As a consequence, they require, at least, **two or several data records to exist on a web page** for the region extractor to work.

My other options are:

- They require, at least, two or several data records **on a web page**
- they require, at least, two or several data records **be on a web page**
- they require, at least, two or several data records **to be on a web page**
- they require **the existence of  at least two or several data records on a web page**
- they require **the presence of  at least two or several data records on a web page**

Which pattern of the above is more common for the verb "require"?

Comment: The idiomatic locution is **two or more**.  You can say "at least two" or "two or more" but combining them doesn't work.

Comment: It's not clear why the methods require two or more *regions* to work ("...as a consequence...")  Don't the methods need at least two structures which identify the *boundary* of a data region?  Why couldn't the data be extracted from a single data region?

Comment: @TRomano In the first sentence I say *they search for **repetitive** structures*, therefore a pattern (structure) should be repeated at least once so that they can detect it. In other words, at least two similar data records is required.

Comment: @TRomano You are right in your first comment, however you can assume some of them require two and maybe some require more.

Comment: The first sentence refers to  repetitive structures which *identify*  (your word) data records. From that sentence, one understands that the repeated structures and the data record they serve to identify are not one and the same thing.  When the reader reaches the second sentence, which begins "as a consequence", the reader asks "As a consequence of *what*, exactly?"

Comment: @tromano if I remove "as a consequence" it would become ok? Anyway I want to count a disadvantage of them.

Comment: Removing **as a consequence** results in two facts  that are not logically connected, which is fine, especially if the logical relationship is unclear. Perhaps the second sentence could be elaborated with a *because*-clause.  Why are two data records required? Does the second instance of the pattern corroborate the pattern?

Comment: @tromano I answered your question in my first comment above. Did you read it? Simply  repetitive means the occurrence of something at least twice. Note that these methods are unsupervised and must discover the patterns by themselves.

Comment: You simply repeated the statement: "The pattern must be repeated at least once so that they can detect it". You did not explain why the repetition was necessary. Are these patterns not conventional but arbitrary?

Comment: @tromano sorry! I don't know what you don't understand about it. Suppose your supposed to find a repetitive pattern in "ABCDEF". What is it? You can't say, but find it in "ABFABG". It's "AB" because it was apeared twice. If I've still missed a point please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first 3 options are not correct.

> They require, at least, two or several data records on a web page

This one doesn't sound correct or natural to me.

> They require, at least, two or several data records be on a web page

This one is grammarly incorrect, the "to" is missing between *records* and *be*, that's how it was supposed to be: *They require, at least, two or several data records to be on a web page*. Anyway, it doesn't sound natural too, I guess "*to be*" wouldn't be suitable for "*two or several data records*"

> They require the existence of at least two or several data records on a web page

This one sounds good to me, and is suitable for "*two or several data records"* Among all these options, I'd prefer to use this one, it suits more in that context.

**However, here is my suggestion**:

> `They require the web page to have at least two data records`

I guess this would be the most proper for this sentence, since you are saying that the they require the *web page* to have some requirements. If you replace the placement of "*web page*" from the bottom to the beginning, it will sound better and more proper.

Comment: I'm not crazy about the phrase "two or several" -- it's confusing and redundant, and I think it's what throws off the entire sentence.  Either "Two or more" or "several" works fine, and makes the sentence more or less acceptable.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, since he is giving one requirement, "at least", he

Comment: he could have changed it for: "They require the web page to have at least 2 data records" several data records would not be necessary, it's just necessary to describe the minimum requirement.

Comment: @Andrew and DavydDiniz what about the rest of the sentence? could it be: "They require the web page to have at least 2 data records **to work/ for them to work**""

Comment: By the way I prefer " ... the page to **contain** two data records..." hows that?

Comment: @Ahmad I have no trouble with the rest of the sentence.  It's the "two or several" which is confusing.  I've always thought the order to be "a pair, a few, several", to mean "two, around three, four to around eight or nine, depending".

Comment: "They require the web page to have at least 2 data records to work"
this would be acceptable, and like Andrew said above, the problem isn't the rest of the sentence, the problem is located at "at least two or several", 'at least' means a minimum requirement, so since you used this as a minimum requirement, "several" would not fit with "at least".

Comment: @Ahmad by the way, "They require the page to contain at least two...." is also acceptable and sounds good too, 'contain' is placed in a more formal context replacing the verb "have", but both of them are acceptable.